# Creating an object in a Method by using another Method to do it. But I can't get the object

Tags: java, object, methods, undefined

I am currently trying to to write a method that uses another method which in turn creates a new object from another class constructor. But I am somehow not able to get the object that I created. When I try to print the object in the method (that used the method which creates the object) it tells me the object is undefined. I am  confused over how I should solve this problem. The reason I have this other method is because there is a bit too much code in one place, so I tried to make it cleaner. 
Anyhow, I decided to post two codes. The first one is my try on making it shorter and easier for you guys to read. But perhaps, just perhaps it might not have something that I missed in my original code. So I am posting that and my constructor class as well. Hopefully it fits here!
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the first "example" sample of what I am trying to do:

```
public static void GameStart(){
//The print method

    if (Player1){
        playerVäljKort(true);
        int val = readInt("Spara val = 1\nRedigera val = 2");
        if (val == 2){
                            //This is where I am trying to print the object. I've tried doing this in several ways.
            System.out.println(player1Kortlek());
        }
    }
}

public static void playerVäljKort(boolean playerTurn){
           //I fail to define this outside the method.
           Kortlek player1Kortlek = new Kortlek(kort)

Public class Kortlek{
   private static int NewKortlek
   public Kortlek(int kort){


     NewKortlek = kort;
   }

Public String toString(){
return "Number of cards = " + Kortlek + ".";
}

}
```

So if that looks perfectly correct, perhaps there is something I cannot see in my real code. Hopefully this won't kill the entire webpage.
Here is the second and real code sample trying to do the same thing as above:
The Constructor Class:

```
public class Kortlek {

private static int KortlekRedCard1;
private static int KortlekRedCard2;
private static int KortlekRedCard3;
private static int KortlekRedCard4;
private static int KortlekRedCard5;
//private static int KortlekredCard6;
private static int KortlekYellowCard1;
private static int KortlekYellowCard2;
private static int KortlekYellowCard3;
private static int KortlekYellowCard4;
private static int KortlekYellowCard5;
private static int KortlekYellowCard6;
private static int KortlekBlueCard1;
private static int KortlekBlueCard2;
private static int KortlekBlueCard3;
private static int KortlekBlueCard4;
private static int KortlekBlueCard5;
//private static int KortlekblueCard6;
private static int KortlekBear;
private static int KortlekAmmo;
private static int KortlekNuclear;
private static int KortlekHeal;
private static int KortlekSkip;
private static int KortlekTank;
private static int KortlekLandmina;
private static int KortlekSteal;

public Kortlek(int redCard1, int redCard2, int redCard3, int redCard4, int redCard5,
        int yellowCard1, int yellowCard2, int yellowCard3, int yellowCard4, int yellowCard5, int yellowCard6,
        int blueCard1, int blueCard2, int blueCard3, int blueCard4, int blueCard5,
        int bear, int ammo, int nuclear, int heal, int skip, int tank, int landmina, int steal){

    this.KortlekRedCard1 = redCard1;
    this.KortlekRedCard2 = redCard2;
    this.KortlekRedCard3 = redCard3;
    this.KortlekRedCard4 = redCard4;
    this.KortlekRedCard5 = redCard5;
    //this.KortlekredCard6 = redCard6;
    this.KortlekYellowCard1 = yellowCard1;
    this.KortlekYellowCard2 = yellowCard2;
    this.KortlekYellowCard3 = yellowCard3;
    this.KortlekYellowCard4 = yellowCard4;
    this.KortlekYellowCard5 = yellowCard5;
    this.KortlekYellowCard6 = yellowCard6;
    this.KortlekBlueCard1 = blueCard1;
    this.KortlekBlueCard2 = blueCard2;
    this.KortlekBlueCard3 = blueCard3;
    this.KortlekBlueCard4 = blueCard4;
    this.KortlekBlueCard5 = blueCard5;
    //KortlekblueCard6 = blueCard6;
    this.KortlekBear = bear;
    this.KortlekAmmo = ammo;
    this.KortlekNuclear = nuclear;
    this.KortlekHeal = heal;
    this.KortlekSkip = skip;
    this.KortlekTank = tank;
    this.KortlekLandmina = landmina;
    this.KortlekSteal = steal;

    /*if (redCard1 > 4 || redCard2 > 4 || redCard3 > 4 || redCard4 > 4 || redCard5 > 4 ||
         yellowCard1 > 4 || yellowCard2 > 4 || yellowCard3 > 4 || yellowCard4 > 4 || yellowCard5 > 4 ||
         yellowCard6 > 4 || blueCard1 > 4 || blueCard2 > 4 || blueCard3 > 4 || blueCard4 > 4 || blueCard5 > 4 ||
         specialCardBear > 4 || specialCardAmmo > 4 || specialCardNuclear > 8 || 
         specialCardHeal > 8 || specialCardSkip > 10 || specialCardTank > 4 || specialCardBomb > 10 || 
         specialCardSteal > 8 /* || KortlekNumber > 50*//*){
        System.out.println("Du tog för många kort av någon sort.");
    }*/

}

/*public static void redCard(){
    KortlekredCard1;

}*/

/*
 * Kortnamn
 * Pistol
 * Hagelgevär
 * Granat(non-Javadoc)
 * Granatkastare
 * Bazooka
 * 
 * Air Gun
 * Lastersiktare
 * Hagelbössa
 * Maskingevär
 * Kulspruta
 * Sniper
 * 
 * Käpp
 * Strykjärn
 * Stekpanna
 * Goldklubba
 * Järnstövlar
 * 
 * Bear
 * Ammo
 * Nuclear
 * Heal
 * Skip
 * Tank
 * Landmina
 * Steal
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */

public String toString(){
    return "1st Rött kort Pistol = " + KortlekRedCard1 + "/4\n2nd Rött kort Hagelgevär = " + KortlekRedCard2
            + "/4\n3rd Rött kort Granat = " + KortlekRedCard3 + "/4\n4th Rött kort Granatkastare = "
            + KortlekRedCard4 + "/4\n5th Rött kort Bazooka = " + KortlekRedCard5 + "/4\n1st Gult kort Air Gun = "
            + KortlekYellowCard1 + "/4\n2st Gult kort Lasersiktare = " + KortlekYellowCard2 
            + "/4\n3rd Gult kort Hagelbössa = " + KortlekYellowCard3 + "/4\n4th Gult kort Maskingevär = "
            + KortlekYellowCard4 + "/4\n5th Gult kort Kulspruta = " + KortlekYellowCard5 
            + "/4\n6th Gult kort Sniper = " + KortlekYellowCard6 + "/4\n1st Blått kort Käpp = "
            + KortlekBlueCard1 + "/4\n2nd Blått kort Strykjärn = " + KortlekBlueCard2 + "/4\n3rd Blått kort Stekpanna = "
            + KortlekBlueCard3 + "/4\n4th Blått kort Golfklubba = " + KortlekBlueCard4
            + "/4\n5th Blått kort Järnstövlar = " + KortlekBlueCard5 + "/4\n1st Special kort Bear = "
            + KortlekBear + "/4\n2nd Special kort Ammo = " + KortlekAmmo + "/8\n3rd Special kort Nuclear = "
            + KortlekNuclear + "/8\n4th Special kort Heal = " + KortlekHeal + "/8\n5th Special kort Skip = "
            + KortlekSkip + "/10n6th Special kort Tank = " + KortlekTank + "/4n7th Special kort Landmina = "
            + KortlekLandmina + "/10\n8th Special kort Steal = " + KortlekSteal + "/8\n";
}
}
```

The print / main Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class KortMain {

//public static boolean Player1;
//public static boolean Player2;
private static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

public static String readString(String str){
    System.out.print(str);
    return userInput.nextLine();
}

public static int readInt(String str){
    System.out.print(str);
    int i = userInput.nextInt();
    userInput.nextLine();
    return i;
}

/*public static void playerStats(){
    if (Hp == 0 || Kort == 0){
        System.out.println("You lose!");
    }
}*/

public static void playerVäljKort(boolean playerTurn){
    //boolean kortObjekt = true;

    int kortCounter = 0;

    int redCard1 = 0;
    int redCard2 = 0;
    int redCard3 = 0;
    int redCard4 = 0;
    int redCard5 = 0;
    int yellowCard1 = 0;
    int yellowCard2 = 0;
    int yellowCard3 = 0;
    int yellowCard4 = 0;
    int yellowCard5 = 0;
    int yellowCard6 = 0;
    int blueCard1 = 0;
    int blueCard2 = 0;
    int blueCard3 = 0;
    int blueCard4 = 0;
    int blueCard5 = 0;
    int bear = 0;
    int ammo = 0;
    int nuclear = 0;
    int heal = 0;
    int skip = 0;
    int tank = 0;
    int landmina = 0;
    int steal = 0;
    String[] kortVal = {"Välj 50 kort.\n\n1st Rött kort Pistol (Max 4): ", 
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n2nd Rött kort Hagelgevär (Max 4): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n3rd Rött kort Granat (Max 4): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n4th Rött kort Granatkastare (Max 4): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n5th Rött kort Bazooka (Max 4): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n1st Gult kort Air Gun (Max 4): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n2st Gult kort Lasersiktare (Max 4): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n3rd Gult kort Hagelbössa (Max 4): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n4th Gult kort Maskingevär (Max 4): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n5th Gult kort Kulspruta (Max 4): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n6th Gult kort Sniper (Max 4): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n1st Blått kort Käpp (Max 4): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n2nd Blått kort Strykjärn (Max 4): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n3rd Blått kort Stekpanna (Max 4): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n4th Blått kort Golfklubba (Max 4): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n5th Blått kort Järnstövlar (Max 4): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n1st Special kort Bear (Max 4): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n2nd Special kort Ammo (Max 8): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n3rd Special kort Nuclear (Max 8): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n4th Special kort Heal (Max 8): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n5th Special kort Skip (Max 10): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n6th Special kort Tank (Max 4): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n7th Special kort Landmina (Max 10): ",
            "Du har hitills valt " + kortCounter + " kort.\n8th Special kort Steal (Max 8): "};
    for (int kortLoop = 0; kortLoop > kortVal.length; kortLoop++){
        switch (kortLoop){
        case 0:
            redCard1 = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += redCard1;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            redCard2 = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += redCard2;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            redCard3 = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += redCard3;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            redCard4 = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += redCard4;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            redCard5 = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += redCard5;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 5: 
            yellowCard1 = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += yellowCard1;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            yellowCard2 = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += yellowCard2;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 7:
            yellowCard3 = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += yellowCard3;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 8:
            yellowCard4 = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += yellowCard4;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 9:
            yellowCard5 = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += yellowCard5;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 10:
            yellowCard6 = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += yellowCard6;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 11:
            blueCard1 = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += blueCard1;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 12:
            blueCard2 = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += blueCard2;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 13:
            blueCard3 = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += blueCard3;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 14:
            blueCard4 = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += blueCard4;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 15:
            blueCard5 = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += blueCard5;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 16:
            bear = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += bear;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 17:
            ammo = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += ammo;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 18:
            nuclear = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += nuclear;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 19:
            heal = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += heal;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 20:
            skip = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += skip;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 21:
            tank = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += tank;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 22:
            landmina = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += landmina;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        case 23:
            steal = readInt(kortVal[kortLoop]);
            kortCounter += steal;
            if (kortCounter >= 50){
                kortLoop = kortVal.length;
            }
            break;
        }

    }

    if (playerTurn){
        Kortlek player1Kortlek = new Kortlek(redCard1, redCard2, redCard3, redCard4, redCard5, yellowCard1, 
                yellowCard2, yellowCard3, yellowCard4, yellowCard5, yellowCard6, blueCard1, blueCard2,
                blueCard3, blueCard4, blueCard5, bear, ammo, nuclear, heal, skip, tank, landmina, steal);

    }
    else{
        Kortlek player2Kortlek = new Kortlek(redCard1, redCard2, redCard3, redCard4, redCard5, yellowCard1, 
                yellowCard2, yellowCard3, yellowCard4, yellowCard5, yellowCard6, blueCard1, blueCard2,
                blueCard3, blueCard4, blueCard5, bear, ammo, nuclear, heal, skip, tank, landmina, steal);
    }
}

public static void GameStart(){
    boolean Player1 = true;
    boolean Player2 = false;

    if (Player1){
        playerVäljKort(true);
        int val = readInt("Spara val = 1\nRedigera val = 2");
        if (val == 2){
            System.out.println(player1Kortlek());
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    GameStart();
}
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  Your top code does not even look like it will compile.  Please edit to a minimal, CORRECT code sample.

Comment: I find your `if (Player1)` in your `static GameStart` suspicious, but I also note you have no `player1Kortlek();`... just a `player1Kortlek` <-- NO PARENS.

Comment: @ Elliott Frisch
I don't understand? The parenthesis are right there in the code?
@ OldProgrammer
Sorry if its unclear. Indeed, the top code won't compile but as I said, its a quick version I tried to make in order to explain the real code below. It won't compile because definitions of etc variables like Player1 are missing. As well as the class name. Please bear in mind it focuses only on the important part. To explain the problem, not to run as a ready program.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch
Sorry I misunderstood your comment. I've tried removing the parentheses but then it becomes and undefined variabel.

Comment: @user3130840 You haven't posted a method named `player1Kortlek`.

Comment: player1Kortlek is an object created from a method (or constructor) called "Kortlek" in this code. player1Kortlek should be defined as such but it won't reach to my print method. Thats the problem.

Comment: @user3130840: You have to declare `player1Kortlek` in `KortMain` as static member, if you want to access it from other static functions. If you do as described in your code, you won't be able to access it anywhere but from the body of the if, where it was declared.

Comment: @fabian: I can't even access it within the if method. I tried to make the method non-void and return the object but its undefined even right under the code where I created the object! And how can I make an object static? I found no clues on the internet that points me in the right direction :S

Comment: @user3130840: What I meant was: Declare them the same way you declared KortlekRedCard1, KortlekBlueCard5, ... in Kortlek (however declare them in KortMain, not in Kortlek) then you have to change the declaration with assignment in playerVäljKort to an assignment. (remove the variable type) Note: If you declare a variable inside (corresponding) {} brackets inside a method, they will no longer be visible after the }

Answer (score -1):

Seemed player1Kortlek is An Kortlek Object,but not a method.

when using println,it will call object's toString method,

so you need to:

1)just Override the class Kortlek' toString method correctly

2)use System.out.println(**player1Kortlek**) to display informaiton;

Comment: What happens ? why give me a -1 ?Have you consider the answer seriously?

Comment: If you look at the code he has overridden the toString method, and even if he hadn't it would print the objects memory address and class name.

Comment: You probably got downvoted because your solution is already in the OP's code. You haven't actually provided any help. Also, don't assume it was the OP that downvoted you, it could have been any of the ~2.5 million users on this site.

Comment: Thanks for your help xiao wang. I really appreciate it! Though, as the others above says, I believe this is exactly what I've already tried to do. The problem is that the object is still undefined in the code, which I think it shouldn't be but I am obviously in wrong because it won't work. Sorry again if my question and code is unclear.

Comment: well ,thanks for your reply,Have you fixed it yet ? My previous answer give you a two-step checklist,maybe not too clear,if you feel hard,I'm glad to help as I can.